# How to send data via POST or GET in Mod_Python?

Tags: python, apache, post, mod-python

With JS, i send a AJAX post request.

```
 $.ajax(
        {method:"POST",
        url:"https://my/website/send_data.py",
        data:JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
```

On my Apache2 mod_Python server, I wish for my python file to access `data`. How can i do this?

```
def index(req):
    # data = ??
```

---

PS: here is how to reproduce the problem. Create `testjson.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "testjson.py");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(res) { console.log(xhr.responseText); };
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({'foo': '0', 'bar': '1'}));
</script>
```

and create `testjson.py` containing:

```
from mod_python import apache 

def index(req):
    req.content_type = "application/json"
    req.write("hello")
    data = req.read()
    return apache.OK
```

Create a `.htaccess` containing:

```
AddHandler mod_python .py
PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
```

Here is the result:

> testjson.html:10 POST http://localhost/test_py/testjson.py 501 (Not Implemented)

[image]

Comment: @fedterzi Unless i'm mistaking those posts are related to vanilla Python, not to mod_python frameworks.

Comment: @fedterzi No, it's not a duplicate, it's specific to mod_python.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen How did you solve the problem in the meantime? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry. I stepped away from Apache and mod_python, instead now using django with nginx.

Comment: But, possibly the same code is usable. Within the index function i set `data = req.POST.get('data',False)`

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen Could you post this as an answer? A general answer working for mod_python would be great.

Comment: @Basj I can't be sure if this will work with mod_python. I no longer have a setup running mod_python.

Comment: @MartijnPieters maybe an idea? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed by Grisha (mod_python's author) in a private communication, here is the reason why `application/json` is not supported and outputs a "HTTP 501 Not implemented" error:

https://github.com/grisha/mod_python/blob/master/lib/python/mod_python/util.py#L284

The solution is either to modify this, or to use a regular `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, or to use something else than the `mod_python.publisher` handler.

Example with `mod_python` and `PythonHandler mod_python.publisher`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3, '&=test', "jkl", {'foo': 'bar'}]); // the data to send
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "testjson.py");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(res) { console.log(xhr.responseText); };
xhr.send('data=' + encodeURIComponent(data));
</script>
```

Server-side:

```
import json
from mod_python import apache 

def index(req):
    data = json.loads(req.form['data'])
    x = data[-1]['foo']
    req.write("value: " + x)
```

Output:

> value: bar

Success!

Answer (score 1):

From [Mod_python docs](http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pythonapi.html#overview-of-a-request-handler):

> Client data, such as POST requests, can be read by using the ***request.read()*** function.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but this does not work in the case of a `application/json` request. See the end of the updated question, are you able to reproduce the problem too?

Comment: OK.
It seems like a configuration problem.

Comment: I tried on another fresh server wtih apache, mod_php, python, etc. and it's the same: HTTP 501 not implemented. When I do a GET it works with HTTP 200. Also OP had the same problem. So at least on 3 machines we were able to reproduce the same error.

Comment: I answered in a new answer, as it is something else.

Answer (score 0):

From the Mod Python docs [here](http://modpython.org/live/current/modpython.pdf).

[image: Mod Python Docs]

Here you can do, for example to get the data

```
def index(req):
    data = req.read()
```

Additional Links : http://vandermerwe.co.nz/?p=9

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but this does not work in the case of a `application/json` request. See the end of the updated question.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the website, I think the author ran into a similar problem there.

Comment: @prakharlondhe Can you link to the location? `the website` is a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, from the new edition it looks like a configuration problem.

First, try to set [PythonPath](http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/directives.html#pythonpath) directive.

Secondly, the PythonHandler should be your [file](http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/directives.html#python-handler-directive-syntax), i.e.:

```
PythonHandler testjson
```

Comment: In fact I want to keep `PythonHandler mod_python.publisher` because this allows `example.com/hello.py` to be automatically mapped to running `hello.py`, `example.com/login.py` to be automatically mapped to running `login.py`, instead of hardcoding only one `PythonHandler` and working with only 1 .py file.

Comment: Look here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MODPYTHON-29, and here: http://modpython.org/pipermail/mod_python/2007-May/023761.html